# Why is the maximum voltage of a surge, 6kV inside home wiring?

Tags: protection, circuit-protection, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, mov

I was reading about the benefits and cons of series mode surge protectors vs MOV-based surge protectors for home use.

**First, why is the probability that a surge will exceed 6kV extremely low due to a flashover?**  What is a flashover exactly?  Is a flashover when a surge entering the main panel arcs over to the bus bar, reducing the possible voltage to 6kV or is it something else?  And, does a flashover always occur if the voltage is high enough?

**I also read that a 10kV surge *might* be possible within the house wiring within a reasonable probability.  Is this true?**  The source was from a manufacturer and I've found most info published by manufacturers to be somewhat biased.

**If a surge, even one caused by a lightning strike, will unlikely exceed 6kV due to a flashover, why is a whole house surge protector necessary?**  Wouldn't just a point-of-use surge protector be sufficient since it can withstand a 6kV surge?

**Is it true that series mode surge protectors are better than MOV-based surge protectors** because they do not have an MOV that eventually fails; instead, they will last indefinitely.  Second, they do not divert any part of the surge to the ground wire like an MOV does, which apparently prevents the surge from affecting nearby plugged-in equipment due to the sharing of the same ground wire.  Third, this surge may expand contamination by spreading into data lines such as telephone, ethernet, and cable lines while a series mode protector will not do this.  Is this all true?

**Is a prolonged surge possible?  If so, would that make series mode surge protectors ineffective since their "electrical sink" is only about 600 joules?**  In other words, most surges are about 10 joules but if a surge is prolonged enough so that more than 600 joules are absorbed by the series mode surge protector, it will then act as a direct conductor so the surge will travel directly to the protected device.  Is this a likely event (within .01%)?  Is this why series mode surge protector manufacturers do not specify their maximum continuous operating voltage (MCOV).  It seems strange since I've also read that MCOV is an important piece of info when assessing a surge protector.

**For an MOV-based surge protector, at what voltage does the shunted remnant surge start to damage nearby equipment and data lines?**  In other words, instead of safely dissipating into the ground that is located fairly far away (30+ ft) and that is connected by wires with a lot of bends, at what voltage will the surge start to damage nearby equipment?  Even despite the increased impedance due to the previous reasons, why would a surge do this if all devices have the same ground potential?

Sorry for the original question leading to so many other questions.  I just have so many questions.  I have literally zero electrical experience; I didn't even learn any in high school physics.  So, even though I've spent many *days*, trying to learn this stuff on my own, the learning curve has been unbearably steep.  I have downloaded and read as many as 50 articles/papers.  It's been like trying to walk through waist-high mud.  I have no one I can ask even the simplest questions!

Edification on any of these subjects would be extremely helpful!  (I boldened the questions to make the entire body easier to read.)

Comment: A flashover is when the voltage between conductors exceeds the insulation capability and an arc occurs between them.

Comment: TL;dr too many questions but meter arc gap for 6kV is low capacitance which reduces ionization time. Thus a LPF not only attenuates peak voltage but reduces BW of EMI while the arc is very broadband and is best to spew outside for dI/dt but 10kV might be possible from a low pF source as a Flyback source. Lightning rise time and decay is standardized for midrange coupling. 1, 10us

Comment: Recall effects of rise time=0.35/fBW

Comment: Technically, without picking on brand data or ads, can you state what a series mode surge suppressor is in terms of its circuitry and components.

Comment: The activation time of ionization is always greater than the risetime

Comment: Hi, everyone.  Thanks for your help!  A series mode surge protector uses a bank of inductors, capacitors, and resistors to absorb surges instead of diverting surges as an MOV does.  It also only provides protection on the L-N line.  The ground wire is not touched.  Whatever energy that is absorbed is slowly dissipated as heat and also slowly released into the neutral wire.

Thanks for the info you guys.  Where does the arc occur in a flashover?  Is it in the main panel?

Comment: Anyone can explain where the flashover actually occurs?  Is it always in the main panel?  Or, does it occur due to the insulation melting in the conductor wires?